# Hadoop MapReduce example command not found

Tags: bigdata, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

I've installed the Hadoop file and I'm trying to run the MapReduce example in the terminal, but am getting the command not found message, can someone help me with this issue, thanks.

Ismails-MacBook-Pro:mapreduce korir$ hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar
-bash: hadoop: command not found

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop command is only recognized from within your hadoop-2.7.3/bin folder. Unless you set the PATH environment variable to include that path.

Execute the command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/korir/hadoop-install-hadoop-2.7.3/bin
```

Consider adding this to a bashrc file to make it permanent.